# Vim textwidth not being applied (although it appears to be set)

Tags: vim

I have a custom vimrc file and I'm using gVim on Windows. Within my vimrc, I set textwidth to 100 for a particular language using "autocmd filetype".

When I type

> :echo &textwidth

it outputs 100, so it would appear that worked. When I type

> :verbose set tw

it confirms that the textwidth is 100 and even demonstrates that it is coming from my custom vimrc.

However, when I edit source in the said language mode, it is apparent that vim is operating with an 80 text width, making everything beyond 80 characters red.

Why this contradiction?

I know textwidth could be overwritten by various things, in theory. However, it seems that vim is telling me that the setting is currently what I want it to be!

How does one explain this contradiction between the value textwidth apparently has and what vim is actually enforcing in practice?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, the culprit was another line in my vimrc:

```
match ErrorMsg '\%>80v.\+
```

That was what I was trying to tweak, not textwidth.

Comment: If you have vim 7.3 or higher you may want to look into `colorcolumn`. E.g. `:set colorcolumn=81` or `:set colorcolumn=+1`. See `:h 'cc'` for more.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using that as well. (Thanks for thinking of, though)